# Reinitialize variable created as variable

Tags: bash, variables

I have an array that contains variable names. In these variables I am assigning values using cycle. Then I am passing these variable names with assigned values ot another function, which checks valid input.

What I need to acomplish is to check if the variable's value contains specific symbol, and if it does, then truncate this value.

Example: when asked for "Admin gateway: " I enter for example value 192.168.1.254/20 (which is nonsense), I want this value to be truncated to 192.168.1.254

Following initialization `$1="something"` does not work, it returns error `admGW=192.168.1.254: command not found`

I have tried something like `declare $1="something"`, but this will only create another local variable visible within current function. I need to reinitialize existing global variable instead. This is maybe not the best approach, but I'm curious if this kind of variable initialization is possible.

Sample code:

```
#!/bin/bash
read_variables(){
    all_vars_desc=("Admin IP/mask: " "Admin gateway: ")
    all_vars_name=("admIP" "admGW")

    for ((i=0; i<${#all_vars_desc[*]}; i++)); do
        read -p "${all_vars_desc[$i]}" ${all_vars_name[$i]}
        check_value ${all_vars_name[$i]} "${!all_vars_name[$i]}"
    done
}

check_value(){
    case $1 in
        *IP) ;; #some code
        *GW) if [[ "$2" == */* ]]; then
                 $1=$(echo "$2" | awk -F/ '{print $1}')
                 echo "Truncating to ${!1}"
             fi;;
    esac
}

read_variables
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you tried using the `declare` on `$1` in your `check_value()` the variable definition is limited to local scope, but `declare` has a `-g` flag for making the variable global. Change the *incorrect* line

```
$1=$(echo "$2" | awk -F/ '{print $1}')
```

to

```
delcare -g "$1"=$(echo "$2" | awk -F/ '{print $1}')
```

See more about the [declare built-in](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/declare) command.

I modified your script to print the elements at the end of the script like below and

```
for ((i=0; i<${#all_vars_name[*]}; i++)); do
    echo ${!all_vars_name[$i]}
done
```

Running now with debugger mode (`bash -x`), it produced the result as you needed,

```
$ bash -x script.sh
+ read_variables
+ all_vars_desc=("Admin IP/mask: " "Admin gateway: ")
+ all_vars_name=("admIP" "admGW")
+ (( i=0 ))
+ (( i<2 ))
+ read -p 'Admin IP/mask: ' admIP
Admin IP/mask: 1.1.1.1/32
+ check_value admIP 1.1.1.1/32
+ case $1 in
+ (( i++ ))
+ (( i<2 ))
+ read -p 'Admin gateway: ' admGW
Admin gateway: 2.2.2.2/32
+ check_value admGW 2.2.2.2/32
+ case $1 in
+ [[ 2.2.2.2/32 == */* ]]
++ echo 2.2.2.2/32
++ awk -F/ '{print $1}'
+ declare -g admGW=2.2.2.2
+ echo 'Truncating to 2.2.2.2'
Truncating to 2.2.2.2
+ (( i++ ))
+ (( i<2 ))
+ (( i=0 ))
+ (( i<2 ))
+ echo 1.1.1.1/32
1.1.1.1/32
+ (( i++ ))
+ (( i<2 ))
+ echo 2.2.2.2
2.2.2.2
+ (( i++ ))
+ (( i<2 ))
```

and in normal mode, to confirm the variable values are updated in the main function

```
$ bash script.sh
Admin IP/mask: 1.1.1.1/32
Admin gateway: 2.2.2.2/32
Truncating to 2.2.2.2
1.1.1.1/32
2.2.2.2
```

---

Since OP had a relatively older version of `bash`, and `declare -g` is available from `bash 4.2` onwards only. In older `bash` versions, you can still remove the line with the `declare` and the subsequent line with indirect variable expansion and just do

```
eval "$(printf %s=%q "$1" "$(echo "$2" | awk -F/ '{print $1}')")"
```

Since you are using `eval` here, you need to be absolutely sure about *sanitizing* the right hand side correctly i.e. in a way knowing *absolutely* sure what you are passing in `$2`, see [BashFAQ/006](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006) under **Assigning indirect/reference variables**

Comment: Thank you for answer. I have tried declare with attribute "-g" before too (sorry that I didn't mention it), but attribute "-g" is not present in my CentOS virtual machine. `declare [-aAfFilrtux] [-p] [name[=value] ...]`. I am not sure if it will be present on targeted system either. Isn't there any other way how to achieve expected result? "No" can also be an answer :D

Comment: @Lopfest: its not about the CentOS machine, you have an outdated `bash` version. Think you can upgrade it? Can you show us `bash --version`?

Comment: Sure. `GNU bash, version 4.1.2(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)`

Comment: @Lopfest: Refer my update, which might work for you in your `bash` version

Comment: I have updated my bash to version `GNU bash, version 4.3.0(1)-release (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)` and still no "-g" atrribute available. Also as I told, I'm not sure if this atrribute will be available on targeted server where this script will run.

Anyway, your updated answer works great! Question: what input could cause unexpected behavior here? I'm trying various inputs and everything seems to work correctly.

Comment: @Lopfest: Its just the nature of `eval` has the potential to execute "dirty" data. Dirty data is any data that has not been rewritten as safe-for-use

Comment: @Lopfest: It is worth having a read on the `FAQ` link I shared! cheers!

Comment: Don't use `awk` here; just use parameter substitution. `declare -g "$1=${2%%/*}"`

Comment: @chepner : Fair point on using parameter substitution but OP does not have the bash version to support -g

Comment: `declare -g` is completely independent of using `awk`.

Comment: Thanks for improvement proposal @chepner. In my case it will be `eval "$(printf %s=%q "$1" "${2%%/*}")"` and its working great.